# I need to send an Email with an attachment using Java. If the attachment is not found, skip it and send mail

Tags: java, automation

I am sending an email on a daily basis, based on the files downloaded from an Email Inbox. On certain days, one or more files might be missing. I would like to send mail even if the an attachment is missing. For Ex. There are 4 Files in a folder. Each file name needs to be attached to a particular string as the File name is being put in an html tag in Mail Body. If any of this file is missing, I am unable to send mail and getting FileNotFound JavaMail Exception.

```
    package com.ExcelFileReader;
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


import common.FolderCreate;



public class SendingMails {
    static ConfigurationReader configreader;
public void SendingMail( String feduptime, String IdbiUpTime, String SibUpTime, String OrbisUptime,String axisfileret, String IIFileret, String ACNFileret, String WKFileret, String Axisuptime, String BBKUptime, String hdfcUpTime) throws IOException, AddressException, MessagingException{



        
        configreader = new ConfigurationReader();
//      final String username = configFileReader.EmailSenderUsername();
//        final String password = configFileReader.EmailSenderPassword();
       
    final String username = configreader.EmailSenderUsername();
    final String password = configreader.EmailSenderPassword();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host",configreader.smtphost());
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", configreader.smtpport());
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        
        
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

       // try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(configreader.senderEmail()));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(configreader.receiverEmail())
            );
            message.setSubject(configreader.Subjectline()+ " "+LocalDate.now());
            
            String AxisFileloc = configreader.AxisFolder();
            String IIFileloc = configreader.BBKAxisConvFolder();
            String acnFileloc = configreader.BBKAxisConvFolder();
            String wkFileloc = configreader.BBKAxisConvFolder();
//            String ACNFileloc = configreader.BBKAxisConvFolder();
            String HdfcFileloc = configreader.hdfcLocation();
            String FedFileloc = configreader.FedBankFilePath();
            String IdbiFileloc = configreader.FedBankFilePath();
            String SibFileloc = configreader.FedBankFilePath();
            String OrbFileloc = configreader.FedBankFilePath();
            
            String fedfile = "File Not found";
            String Idbifile = "File Not found";
            String SibFile = "File Not found";
            String Orbisfile =  "File Not found";
            String AxisFile = "";
            String IIFile = "File Not found";
            String bbkFile = "";
            String ACNFile = "File Not found";
            String WKFile = "File Not found";
            String hdfcFile = "";
            String hdfcFileret = "_SHINYVIEWGEOJITsumm.xls";
            String Txtfile = "";
            
            File directory7 = new File(FedFileloc);
            File[] files7 = directory7.listFiles();
            for(File file7:files7) {
                Txtfile =  file7.getName();
               
                    if(Txtfile.contains("NRI_PIS"))
                    {
                        fedfile = Txtfile;
                    }
                    else if(Txtfile.contains("Acct_status_RNEPS_RNOPS_GESBNRI"))
                    {
                        Idbifile = Txtfile;
                    }
                    else if(Txtfile.contains("pis_bal_text"))
                    {
                        SibFile = Txtfile;
                    }
                    else if(Txtfile.contains("Geojit Financial"))
                    {
                        Orbisfile = Txtfile;
                    }

            }
            
            
        //Axis Bank 
File directory = new File(AxisFileloc);
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
  public boolean accept(File directory)
  {
      return directory.getName().endsWith("csv");
  }
};
            File[] files1 = directory.listFiles(filter);
           for(File file:files1) {
               if(file.exists()) {
                   System.out.println("File name1: "+file.getName());
                   
                       AxisFile =  file.getName();
                   
                      
                  }
               
               else
               {
               AxisFile = "Axis File not found";
               Axisuptime = "N/A";
               }
               }
        
           
         //II Loc Bank  
           File directory2 = new File(IIFileloc);
           FileFilter filter2 = new FileFilter() {
                  
               public boolean accept(File directory2)
               {
                   return directory2.getName().endsWith("csv");
               }
             };
                         File[] files2 = directory2.listFiles(filter2);
                         for(File file:files2) {
                         
                            bbkFile = file.getName();
                            if(bbkFile.equalsIgnoreCase("II Loc Balance"))
                            {
                                IIFile = bbkFile;
                            }
                            else if(bbkFile.equalsIgnoreCase("ACN Balance"))
                            {
                                ACNFile = bbkFile;
                            }
                            else if(bbkFile.equalsIgnoreCase("Geojit Balance"))
                            {
                                WKFile = bbkFile;
                            }
                                
                          } 
                       

//         
//         //HDFC Location
         File directory4 = new File(HdfcFileloc);
         FileFilter filter4 = new FileFilter() {
          
           public boolean accept(File directory4)
           {
               return directory4.getName().endsWith("csv");
           }
         };
                     File[] files4 = directory4.listFiles(filter4);
        
        for(File file:files4) {
          // if(file.isFile()) {
              if(file.exists()) {
               System.out.println("File name4: "+file.getName());
              hdfcFile =  file.getName();
              
           }else
           {
              hdfcFileret = "File not found";
              hdfcUpTime = "N/A";
           }
        }
        
        if(fedfile =="File Not found")
        {
            feduptime = "N/A";
        }
        if(Idbifile =="File Not found")
        {
            IdbiUpTime = "N/A";
        }
        if(SibFile =="File Not found")
        {
            SibUpTime = "N/A";
        }
        if(Orbisfile =="File Not found")
        {
            OrbisUptime = "N/A";
        }
        
           
           
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            message.setContent(multipart);
            
           MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = 
                   createTextPart
                   ("<html><head><style>table, th, td {  border: 1px solid black;\r\n"
                            + "}</style></head><body>\r\n"
                        + "<h1></h1>\r\n"
                        + "<p>Hi Team,</p>\r\n" 
                        + "<p>\nPIS File Upload process has been completed successfully.</p>\r\n"
                        +"<p>\nPlease find the details below.</p>\r\n"
                        + "<table >  <tr bgcolor=\"green\"> <th>Balance file updated through Automation</th><th>File Name</th>  <th>File Uploaded Time</th></tr>  <tr>  <td>Federal Bank - PIS File Upload</td>    <td>"
                        + fedfile+"</td> <td>"+ feduptime+"</td> </tr>  <tr>    <td>IDBI Bank - PIS File Upload</td>  <td>"
                        +Idbifile+"</td>  <td>"+ IdbiUpTime+"</td>  </tr> <tr><td>SIB Bank - PIS File Upload</td>  <td>"
                        +SibFile+"</td>  <td>"+SibUpTime+"</td></tr><tr><td>ORBIS - PIS File Upload</td>    <td>"
                        +Orbisfile+"</td> <td>"+OrbisUptime+"</td></tr>   <td>Axis Bank - PIS File Upload</td>    <td>"
                        + axisfileret+"</td> <td>"+ Axisuptime+"</td> </tr>  <tr>    <td>HDFC Bank - PIS File Upload</td>  <td>"
                        +hdfcFileret+"</td>  <td>"+ hdfcUpTime+"</td>  </tr> <tr><td>BBK II Location - PIS File Upload</td>  <td>"
                        +IIFileret+"</td>  <td>"+BBKUptime+"</td></tr><tr><td>BBK ACN Location - PIS File Upload</td>    <td>"
                        +ACNFileret+"</td> <td>"+BBKUptime+"</td></tr><tr><td>BBK WK Location - PIS File Upload</td>    <td>"
                        +WKFileret+"</td> <td>"+BBKUptime+"</td></tr></table>\r\n"
                        + "</body>\r\n"
                        + "</html>"
                        + "<p>\nThe uploaded files has also been attached with the mail.</p>\r\n"
                        + "<p>\nThanks and Regards,</p>\r\n"
                        + "<p>Autobot</p>\r\n", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
           
           if (messageBodyPart1.isMimeType("text/html")) {
               //String html = (String) messageBodyPart1.getContent();
              // String result2 = 
           }
           
           
           
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
          
            try {
                MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = createBinaryPart(AxisFileloc, AxisFile, "application/csv");
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
            }catch(MessagingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
for(File file:files2)           
            {
                //if(file.exists()==true) 
                 //{
    
    if(bbkFile.equalsIgnoreCase("II Loc Balance"))
    {
        IIFile = bbkFile;
        try {
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart3 = createBinaryPart(IIFileloc, IIFile, "application/csv");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart3);
            
            }catch(MessagingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //IIFile = "II file not found";
            }
    }
    else if(bbkFile.equalsIgnoreCase("ACN Balance"))
    {
        ACNFile = bbkFile;
        try {
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart3 = createBinaryPart(IIFileloc, ACNFile, "application/csv");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart3);
            
            }catch(MessagingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //IIFile = "II file not found";
            }
    }
    else if(bbkFile.equalsIgnoreCase("Geojit Balance"))
    {
        WKFile = bbkFile;
        try {
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart3 = createBinaryPart(IIFileloc, WKFile, "application/csv");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart3);
            
            }catch(MessagingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //IIFile = "II file not found";
            }
    }
    
//            try {
//            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart3 = createBinaryPart(IIFileloc, IIFile, "application/csv");
//            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart3);
//            
//            }catch(MessagingException e)
//            {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//              //IIFile = "II file not found";
//            }
                       }

            try {
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart6 = createBinaryPart(HdfcFileloc, hdfcFile, "application/csv");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart6);
            }catch(MessagingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            for(File file:files7)
            {
                try {
                    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart7 = createBinaryPart(FedFileloc, Txtfile, "application/text");
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart7);
                    }catch(MessagingException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        
                    }
            }

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Completion Mail has been sent Successfully");


            

    
    }
    
    public MimeBodyPart createTextPart(String text, String mimeType) throws
     MessagingException { 
         
          MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
      messageBodyPart1.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8"); return messageBodyPart1; }
     

    public MimeBodyPart createBinaryPart(String path, String name, String mimeType) throws MessagingException {
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(Paths.get(path,name).toFile());
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(name);
messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
messageBodyPart.setHeader("ContentType", mimeType);
return messageBodyPart;
}

}
```

In the above, In FedFileLoc there might be 4 files or less. When a file is missing. I should be able to send the mail with the remaining attachments. If there are all 4 files, then each file should be attached with their respective file names.

Comment: What problem are you having?  Are you not able to check for the existence of each file yourself?

Comment: In the above code, I am getting the file name correctly. If it is not existing, the filename is set to "File not found". But if the file is not found. When it comes to Mime attachment part, the code fails and mail is not send when a file is missing.

Comment: TO be more precise, I need the exact file name to be printed in the row corresponding to a bank name. And yet be able to send a mail when a file is missing.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I finally found the answer myself.